# token blacklist outstandingtoken

Tags: django, mongodb, django-rest-framework, jwt

`token_blacklist_outstandingtoken` is the collection in mongodb database which django rest framework use to store tokens assigned to recently registered users. It stores access token well for first user register, but it makes error while inserting second usererror details:

```
djongo.sql2mongo.SQLDecodeError: FAILED SQL: INSERT INTO "token_blacklist_outstandingtoken" ("user_id", "jti", "token", "created_at", "expires_at") VALUES (%(0)s, %(1)s, %(2)s, %(3)s, %(4)s)
Params: [11, 'fe4bbe67b6a4413e81cfca6b4e2919aa', 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoicmVmcmVzaCIsImV4cCI6MTYwOTE3Nzc4MCwianRpIjoiZmU0YmJlNjdiNmE0NDEzZTgxY2ZjYTZiNGUyOTE5YWEiLCJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxMX0.JtyGSL_nJ4iiKXqijvxCkipxMQAxTksFKEP6g5qPGiI', datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 14, 17, 49, 40, 602304), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 28, 17, 49, 40)]
Pymongo error: {'writeErrors': [{'index': 0, 'code': 11000, 'keyPattern': {'jti_hex': 1}, 'keyValue': {'jti_hex': None}, 'errmsg': 'E11000 duplicate key error collection: patientStatus.token_blacklist_outstandingtoken index: token_blacklist_o_jti_hex_d9bdf6f7_uniq dup key: { jti_hex: null }', 'op': {'id': 10, 'user_id': 11, 'jti': 'fe4bbe67b6a4413e81cfca6b4e2919aa', 'token': 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoicmVmcmVzaCIsImV4cCI6MTYwOTE3Nzc4MCwianRpIjoiZmU0YmJlNjdiNmE0NDEzZTgxY2ZjYTZiNGUyOTE5YWEiLCJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxMX0.JtyGSL_nJ4iiKXqijvxCkipxMQAxTksFKEP6g5qPGiI', 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 14, 17, 49, 40, 602304), 'expires_at': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 28, 17, 49, 40), '_id': ObjectId('5fd7a5b444a87611a60654ae')}}], 'writeConcernErrors': [], 'nInserted': 0, 'nUpserted': 0, 'nMatched': 0, 'nModified': 0, 'nRemoved': 0, 'upserted': []}
```

Comment: Hi, have you found any solution, please reply

Comment: The `jti` in the payload is `null` everytime for OP

Comment: Please add more details and information to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is a field called `jti_hex` which has a unique constraint. In your insert, you are not providing a value for it and therefore it is defaulting to `null`.

Due to this default, on the first user creation, a record with `jti_hex=null` gets created. Then upon entering the details for the second user, it tried to insert a default of `null` for `jti_hex` again. This is failing the unique check.

Hope this helps. It is all I could gather based on the error message. If your issue is still not solved, please add more information like the model or code for this insert and I will be able to answer better.

Comment: You can comment, as you have 50+ reputation to comment, then make answer, not do this what you've done that first made an answer, and asked question inside it, then said I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Fair enough. I think my phrasing isn't great. I meant if you want a more specific answer, please provide more details in the question and this is the answer based on info available.

Let me edit that for clarity.